# month begining dates 2 mnths back

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dates in yyyy-dd-mm in a column(col 1).(type = pandas.core.series.Series and dtypes=datetime64[ns]). I need begining of the month date for 2 months prior(col 2)

```
                  col 1                   col2
                  2021-01-07              2020-01-05
```

I have been trying to use timedelta & relative timedelta , but not working. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Since `timedelta` does not have `months` parameter, you can use `dateutil` module instead:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x - relativedelta(months=2))
```